# Which Free Video Compressor do you recommend for Windows?

Tags: video, file-compression

I'm using Windows 7 (I know, quite old), but I'd like to find a video compressor to downsize all of my videos that I put on the computer from my cellphone (they take too much space).

Any recommendation? Thanks,

Comment: What's your budget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opted for Handbrake and I'm quite happy with it. Free and Opensource.

I use Video Quality 30 and the results are good, the size is downsized around 80% with good quality.

The only con is the use of CPU which is obviously quite intensive. I couldn't find the option to batch-resize. But anyways, it is already a good software for basic needs.

- https://handbrake.fr/downloads.php

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use [FFMPEG](https://ffmpeg.org/) from the command line, a batch file *(or of course a python script)*, etc.

- Free gratis & open source
- Cross platform *(it will run on just about anything from a Raspberry Pi up)*.
- A **lot** of possible options to process your videos to make them smaller including:

  - Change compression *on compressed codecs*
  - Change encoding/format
  - Change resolution/rescale
  - Change frame rate
  - Change colour depth
  - Change audio sample rate
  - *lots more* including examining & modifying metadata
- My personal experience is that recoding videos from **some** sources, *with next to no changes* can produce a huge reduction of size, e.g. Skype recorded Online 1 hour meetings being processed to remove the first few minutes of the *"we'll just wait another minute for everybody to join"* are often reduced in size by over 90% with no change of resolution etc.
- It is fast *on my system those 1 hour meetings take <10 mins to process*
- On the down side there are a **lot** of options but on the up side it has its own tag on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ffmpeg) with a lot of help there.

Once you have found a set of settings that work for your specific requirements you can:

1. Put the command required into a batch file or bash script *depending on your platform* for manual processing with a lot less typing.
2. Potentially use a python script, *or similar*, to walk through your directory structure looking for videos that meet some naming pattern and process them in background.

I personally use [MoviePy](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/) as a front end for FFMPEG as I find that easier than calling it directly *(but then again it has been noted that I am a python guy)*.